# Forcing 'normal' footnote labelling

Tags: footnotes

I'm getting footnotes with both the citation and the reference labelled with superscript round parentheses following the sequence number thus:
`1)`, `2)` etc.

I think it may be being caused by the style file, which comes from my publisher.

Is there a way to force normal arabic numbers? I've tried

```
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
```

which doesn't work, and package `footmisc` doesn't appear to have a relevant option.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{book}

\usepackage{wileySTM}
\crop[noinfo]

\begin{document}

This is the text illustrating a problem with the footnotes.\footnote{And this is the offending footnote}

\end{document}
```

The style file is at:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37127482/wileySTM.sty

Thanks, Chris.

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SX. It is very hard to answer your question as we don't know what documentclass you publisher gave you. could you prepare a minimal working example and add a link to your documentclass to help us understand what the problem might be ?

Comment: Thanks Elad.How can I post a link to the style file. Is there somewhere I can upload it to?
Thanks, Chris.

Comment: You could either post the link that was provided for you, or use any free storage provider you can find (i.e. google drive, dropbox, mega...)

Comment: Hi
I've now added a MWE as requested

Comment: Presumably the style file produces this type of label as that is what the publisher wants.  In which case you should not change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sty package redefines `\@makefnmark` and `@makefntext` which is what you want to redefine.

I quickly copied and pasted their definition and removed the extra `)`; please ask whether you can opt to make these changes and still get your work accepted

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{wileySTM}
\crop[noinfo]
\makeatletter
\def\@makefnmark{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}
\renewcommand{\@makefntext}[1]{%
  \hangindent4mm
  \leavevmode
  \hb@xt@4mm{\normalfont\@thefnmark\hss}#1}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

This is the text illustrating a problem with the footnotes.\footnote{And this is the offending footnote}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Also, if you like their sty file for many reasons, but want to keep the *default* style for the footnotes, you could save the commands before loading the package and then reinstate their functioning, as shown below

```
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter
\let\@myfnmark\@makefnmark
\let\@myfntext\@makefntext
\makeatother
\usepackage{wileySTM}
\crop[noinfo]
\makeatletter
\let\@makefnmark\@myfnmark
\let\@makefntext\@myfntext
\makeatother
\begin{document}

This is the text illustrating a problem with the footnotes.\footnote{And this is the offending footnote}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ccfpcl please, if you feel the answer solve your problem, consider accepting it (green tick mark on the left): this way it will be easily searchable in the future.